# Problems while parsing date with NSRegularExpression

Tags: objective-c, regex, swift, cocoa, nsregularexpression

I'm trying to parse string with date format like MM/YY and store month and year variables.

I wrote this code and can't figure out why when I pass string like "1":

- `match.numberOfRanges` == 3
- `match.rangeAtindex(2)` == (9223372036854775807,0)

Here is my code (regex has only two groups, so I don't understand how number of ranges can be even theoretically more than 2).

```
let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^(\\d{1,2})?[\\s/]*(\\d{1,2})?", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.allZeros, error: nil)
// Expiry date string is "1"
let match = regex?.firstMatchInString(expiryDate, options: NSMatchingOptions.allZeros, range: NSMakeRange(0, expiryDateNS.length))

if let match = match {
    let monthRange = match.rangeAtIndex(1)
    // next string works correct - month contains "1"
    var month = expiryDateNS.substringWithRange(monthRange)

    if match.numberOfRanges > 1 {  // match.numberOfRanges returns 3
        let yearRange = match.rangeAtIndex(2) // returns LONG_MAX as location, 0 as length
        // next line will crash
        expiryYear = expiryDateNS.substringWithRange(yearRange)
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
As @matt asked, I'm adding few examples here.

- String "1" should be parsed and stored as `month == "1"` and `expiryYear == ""`
- String "12" should be parsed and stored as `month == "12"` and `expiryYear == ""`
- String "12/45" should be parsed and stored as `month == "12"` and `expiryYear == "45"`

When I'm parsing string "1" with code above `match.numberOfRanges` is 3 and `match.rangeAtindex(2)` is (9223372036854775807,0)

Comment: If the string _is_ a date, you would do much better to use NSDateFormatter to parse it, because that is what it is for. It will just turn the string into a date, ka-boom.

Comment: It would be a lot more helpful if you would show several target strings you are trying to parse.

Comment: @matt thanks, but I need to go this way.

Comment: Oh, I see. So the question is, why you are crashing with this faulty string?

Comment: Well, obviously your `pattern` is totally wrong. If it were right, you would not match "1" at all.

Comment: "so I don't understand how number of ranges can be even theoretically more than 2)." Because one of the ranges is the whole match. Please read the docs.

Comment: why don't you just split your string "/" and get the first and last components?

Comment: So I still don't see why you are using regular expressions here. But if you must... Here is an online regex tester: https://regex101.com There are many others. Step one for you should be to throw regex patterns and target strings at this until you get a pattern that matches only strings that _should_ match, i.e. that are constructed the way you specify.

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus thanks. It may contain spaces around the "/" separator. Probably split + trim is the way to go. But I still can't figure out the problem in the regex. Thanks.

Comment: @matt I tested pattern on regex101.com and it does exactly what i need. 
Screenshot: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/g7ar3eg9odo94kc/Screenshot%202015-05-18%2016.01.52.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the input string `"1"`, the second capture group `(\\d{1,2})?` is matched
zero times. In that case 
`match.rangeAtIndex(2).location` is `NSNotFound` (which happens to be
`Int.max = 9223372036854775807`).

For the input string `"/12"` the first capture group `(\\d{1,2})?` would
be matched zero times. So you have to check for this cases:

```
var month = ""
var year = ""
if let match = match {
    let monthRange = match.rangeAtIndex(1)
    if monthRange.location != NSNotFound {
        month = expiryDateNS.substringWithRange(monthRange)
    }

    let yearRange = match.rangeAtIndex(2)
    if yearRange.location != NSNotFound {
        year = expiryDateNS.substringWithRange(yearRange)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks martin, I thought about `NSNotFound` and added this check already. Do you know why `numberOfRanges` is 3 in that case?

Comment: @OgreSwamp: Range #0 is the entire pattern, range #1 is what matches the first capture group `(\\d{1,2})`, and range #2 is what matches the second capture group. You always get one range for the entire pattern plus  one for each capture group.

Comment: Thanks. Now that makes perfect sense for me.

Answer (score 1):

For such a simple string and pattern, NSScanner is easier. This function gives the outputs you specified for the inputs you specified:

```
func analyze(s:String) -> (String,String) {
    var result = ("","")
    let sc = NSScanner(string: s)
    var first:Int32 = 0
    let ok = sc.scanInt(&first)
    if ok {
        result.0 = String(first)
        let ok = sc.scanUpToCharactersFromSet(NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet(), intoString: nil)
        if !sc.atEnd {
            var second:Int32 = 0
            let ok = sc.scanInt(&second)
            if ok {
                result.1 = String(second)
            }
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So if you decide to split your string you can do as follow:

```
let date = "12 / 45".stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "", options: .LiteralSearch, range: nil)

let components = date.componentsSeparatedByString("/")
let month =  components.count > 0 ? components.first! : ""
let expiryYear = components.count > 1 ? components.last! : ""
```

Comment: Thanks, @leonardo. I wanted to go with regular expression because it **verifies** and separates values. In case with splitting string by components I need to add this verification manually.